# Issue in generating the xml file from python minidom

Tags: python, xml, minidom

Here is the code:

```
    from xml.dom.minidom import Document

doc = Document()
root = doc.createElement('root')
doc.appendChild(root)
for i in range(1,3):
    main = doc.createElement('item class:=memory')
    root.appendChild(main)
    for j in range(1,3):
        text = doc.createTextNode('DIMM Size'+str(j))
        main.appendChild(text)

print (doc.toprettyxml(indent='\t'))
```

Here is the output:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
    <item class:=memory>
        DIMM Size1
        DIMM Size2
    </item class:=memory>
    <item class:=memory>
        DIMM Size1
        DIMM Size2
    </item class:=memory>
</root>
```

I am trying to generate the file with following code. Is there a way to generate the following output:

```
<root>
    <item class:=memory>
        <p> DIMM Size1 </p>
        <p>DIMM Size2 </p>
    </item>
    <item class:=memory>
        <p>DIMM Size1</p>
        <p>DIMM Size2</p>
    </item>
</root>
```

Comment: Why would you put yourself through the pain and suffering of minidom when ElementTree exists? (Also, `class:=memory`, unlike `class='memory'`, is not valid XML)

Comment: <p></p> is an XML element and needs to be created when using minidom... which you shouldn't use anyway. see @CharlesDuffy comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two quick changes

1. Create a `p` element e.g. `doc.createElement('p')`
2. Don't set attributes manually instead use node.attributes e.g. `main.attributes['class']='memory'`

so your code should look like this

```
from xml.dom.minidom import Document

doc = Document()
root = doc.createElement('root')
doc.appendChild(root)
for i in range(1,3):
    main = doc.createElement('item')
    main.attributes['class']='memory'
    root.appendChild(main)
    for j in range(1,3):
        p = doc.createElement('p')
        text = doc.createTextNode('DIMM Size'+str(j))
        p.appendChild(text)
        main.appendChild(p)

print (doc.toprettyxml(indent='\t'))
```

A long term change would be to use [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) which has more intuitive interface and is easy to use, more so while reading xml e.g. your example in element tree

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as etree

root = etree.Element('root')
for i in range(1,3):
    item = etree.SubElement(root, 'item')
    item.attrib['class']='memory'
    for j in range(1,3):
        p = etree.SubElement(item, 'p')
        p.text = 'DIMM Size %s'%j

print etree.tostring(root)
```